# same code doesn't work on my own project (strcpy) in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on some exercises for school.
The projects i have from my teacher work without any errors.
When i copy the code to a new project made on my computer, it shows this error:
Compiler Warning (level 3) C4996

I looked at both compiler settings and made them equal, this didn't work.
So i tried to make a project property file from my teachers project and insert it into my own project. Also this doesn't work.
Can somebody help me solving this issue?
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
    char s1[32];
    char s2[32];

    strcpy(s1, "abc def.");
    strcpy(s2, "ghi_x");

    printf("s1=\"%s\"    en   s2=\"%s\"\n", s1, s2);
    printf("s1 bevat %d symbolen  en s2 bevat %d symbolen\n", strlen(s1),        strlen(s2));
    printf("De functie strcmp(s1,s2) geeft %d als functiewaarde\n", strcmp(s1, s2));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The Error I get is

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error C4996   'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details

Comment: You may have to add a '\0' at the end to terminate the string.

Comment: Can you post the error you get ?

Comment: No, everything's properly terminated here. I don't see any errors. What is "warning C4496"? Surely your compiler has a manual with descriptions of these?

Comment: Surely the compiler told you which line the warning was for?

Comment: This code looks fine.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4996 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. I agree this can be an unsafe function. But it works from the files i got from my teacher, i would like to use the same way of coding. Oh and i use visual studio community 2017

Comment: MSVC also tells you to use `scanf_s` which is actually no safer than `scanf` because it is even more tricky to use. Use the standard library functions. Add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before the first `#include`.

Comment: This is no longer a C question.  You know the cause of the warning and how to change your code to avoid it.  Suppressing the warning rather than modifying the code to avoid the warning makes this a compiler/tool question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search shows that "Compiler Warning (level 3) C4996" means you're using deprecated functions.  The most likely culprits are your `str*` functions since they are generally unsafe.  Switch to using their `strn*` counterparts (e.g. `strncpy`).

Comment: i agree, but the files i got from my teacher are coded with these functions. I would like to use the same functions as my teacher. There must be a difference in compiler settings but i have no idea on how to find it.

Comment: In that case you aren't asking a C question, you're asking a compiler/tool question.  Please edit your question to add a tag specific to your compiler and modify your question accordingly.